# Clear TOTAL summaryItem - devexpress

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

How can i remove all total summryItem at once

```
gridview1.Columns("Column1").SummaryItem.Collection.Remove(ItemVariable)
```

I try this and it works but is there any way I can delete all Collection like using something like this:

```
 gridview1.TotalSummaryItemCollection.remove ???
```

Comment: `Collection.Clear()`? I've never used DevExpress but it's a suggestion.

Comment: that is not going to work

Comment: Then why not? It's better explaining why instead of just saying it's not going to work, as I don't know anything about DevExpress. ;)

Comment: How about `gridview1.GroupSummary.Clear()`? This was something I found here: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q99980

Comment: that is for group summary, i need for total summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `TotalSummaryItemCollection` for each `TotalSummaryItem` in each `GridColumn`. There are only `GridColumn.Summary` property of class `GridColumnSummaryItemCollection`. This property have the `Clear` method, which allows you to delete all `TotalSummaryItems` from `GridColumn`. So, to remove all `TotalSummaryItems` you must use something like this:

```
foreach (GridColumn gridColumn in gridView1.Columns)
    gridColumn.Summary.Clear();
```